# Reducing frequency of the "Joomla! update available" mails to once per day or once per week

Tags: update, joomla-4.x, system-plugin

Is there a way to reduce the frequency of the automatic "Joomla! Update available" mails? I do not want to disable the plugin, because I want to be notified about updates. But multiple mails per day is just too much. I'd prefer to receive one mail per week, or one per day at most.

Answer (score 2):

At System -> Update -> Extensions -> Options you can change the caching to 24 hours so you only get one email per day.

There does not appear to be any other option apart from disabling the System - Joomla! Update Notification plugin.

Comment: That seems to concern extensions, not Jommla itself. Anyway, I have changed this to 24 and will see what happens.

Comment: This was a tip I found elsewhere and I haven't tested it myself so please do let us know if it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'll report in a day or two if things have changed.

Comment: Changing this option has indeed changed the intervall to more or less one mail per day. It is not a 24 hours intervall exactly, though, but it soes the trick. This sit doesn't have a lot of traffic, so the mail is probably triggered when Google fetches the site map file, which happens at different times.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 4, the setting can also be found under System -> Global Configuration -> Installer -> Updates Caching. The most you can set it to is 24 hours.